# Duplicity: Too many files in target directory

Tags: duplicity, duplicity-backup

I'm trying to use duply backup which is based on duplicitiy. My problem is that my remote target ("GMX mediacenter" via WebDAV) seems to limit the number of files in one directory to 3000 (which is not documented - only my experience). When this limit is reached backup always stops because of `WebDAV response status 507 with reason 'Insufficient Storage'.`

I am seeing the following options:

- Split the source into several parts. Then I still have to risk to reach the limit of 3000 files in the target directory.
- Increase the volume size (`--volsize`), but this will only delay the problem, too.

Do I have any other good options?

Answer (score 1):

not a development issue! so maybe the wrong place to ask your question.

i'd say change your backend! how will you ever guarantee that your backup will hold less than 3000 files exactly?
there are lot's of cheap/free services out there offering 2GB upward.

..ede/duply.net

Comment: You're right - maybe the wrong place here. / I thought about some method to use subdirectories.